# Get a file through Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

When I try to get a file through ajax it is not working but through include in the javascript it is working, now I am new at this and I guess the reason for that is because javascript is executing inside of that code while ajax just executes the file.
So when I use the ajax the code fails at this:

```
$args1 = array();
$gethosts = get_xml_host_objects($args1); //grabbing internal xml data from backend
```

With the reason:

Call to undefined function get_xml_host_objects() in /usr/local/nagiosxi/html/includes/components/googlemap/buildmarkers.inc.php on line 3,

I would like an answer for this particular situation, because I do not understand how to incorporate PHP to work with javascript?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to make PHP use a JavaScript function called get_xml_host_objects?

Comment: Well it looks like I am, but I do not understand how to do it?